# Why I cannot access Yobit API using webclient

Tags: webclient

The code used to work.

The URL in question is

https://yobit.net/api/3/info

It works in IE. It used to work with webclient. It doesn't work in webclient now. And I wonder what the problem is

Suddenly it stops working. So I am checking

```
    Try
        Dim wc = New WebClient
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*")
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
        wc.DownloadString(URL)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I also tried simple version. Not working

```
    Try
        Dim wc = New WebClient
        wc.DownloadString(URL)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

In both cases yobit throw **503 access denied** exception

I use fiddler and try to use internetexplorer to access directly

It works fine

```
GET https://yobit.net/api/3/info HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: yobit.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: __cfduid=de63c60d603f271520b9ee58dfdd257061517932785; cf_clearance=7e58588df28b267842f753567dcdc475d29679a6-1517932789-86400; locale=en
```

If I use webclient this is the header

```
GET https://yobit.net/api/3/info HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: yobit.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Almost the exact same thing.

Let me try another URL

Say http://google.com

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: NID=121=GUd4VKHT_gcwUx-hK39mphuCg93Q_W2fL_yCc-JO3AJkgh74EGajif0537eraLK8ns2EdEQPexOOeBxSlOxVrj8t_AVn21FRme2hAxuLXz4F8aCZExIzME4jaYMBuUp_lnak5Q; OGPC=19004116-3:; 1P_JAR=2018-1-9-7
```

If I use webclient

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Both works.

Comment: Seems like it needs Cookies, which are actually sent when you do it in IE but not when you use code. Is this a authenticated endpoint? Because I don't see you providing any of that information

Comment: No it's not an authenticated endpoint. I seriously do not think cookies is the issue. This is an API. I can clear cookies and I bet it'll still work in IE

Comment: I checked at my end it works in curl, so sure its not issue of cookies. Can you check if it happened after some .NET framework upgrade or something? Can you change the framework versions

Comment: It works on curl? Hmmm....

Comment: That yobit thing is the only thing that doesn't work. All other URL works fine with webclient as it should be

Comment: I changed the frame work to 4.6.1. May be that's the case. I will change that to 4.7.1 or play around and let you know the result. If it works, please make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be different issues here

**Framework Version**

You recently changed the framework version and that has some issue which causes it not to work. You can change the framework versions and see if it helps

**Compression of Data**

`WebClient` by default is not doing decompression and you add headers to request `gzip` data if available. Now there is a possibility that the site didn't enable gzip earlier which made it work for you and now they have enabled gzip responses. You can fix that by changing

```
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
```

to

```
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate")
```

Or if you want the data to come in compressed form only, then you can enable auto decompression as shown in below code

```
class Program
{
    class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            return request;
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var URL = "https://yobit.net/api/3/info";
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*");
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString(URL));
        // TODO: Implement Functionality Here

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

The above example is `C#` and not `VB.NET` but you can easily convert it

[image: Working]

Comment: did you try and does it work? Does it work in your system? In my case, yobit will send 503 error

Comment: @J.Chang, yes it had worked, I tested and then only posted it here

Comment: Your answer is correct. Changing the targeted framework somehow solve the problem. I have no idea why.